# DNS: Can a single server be both a local NS and the Authoritative NS for a domain

Tags: dns

My question is can a single server be both a local NS and the Authoritative NS for a domain or separated servers are required?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you by "local NS" means a recursing resolver, then yes, absolutely. It's even the default setup in BIND. However, it's not a particularly good idea to do so, since it confuses two very different tasks. You'll save yourself headaches and messy diagnosis sessions in the future if you run two name servers, one for authoritative reasons on an outward-facing IP and one for recursing on 127.0.0.1 (and ::1, of course).